# Can I be added as a team member to Enterprise Apple developer team without having paid Apple developer account?

Tags: ios, account, ios-provisioning

As I asked in the title, can I be added as a team member to an Enterprise Apple developer team without having paid Apple developer account? I can't find anything on that.

Comment: and what if the account is registered in apple developer program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody else was wondering the same thing, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sign in to [Apple Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/account) (Enrolled as an **organization**)
2. Then click `Invite People`
3. Enter the email address of the person for inviting as a `Team Member`
4. Click `Invite`. Then the invited person receives the email invitation.
5. The person wants to verify by clicking the link.

Kindly see this [Apple Developer Program Team Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)

Comment: Ok, but my question was if invited person has to have paid developer account?

Comment: I think no need to have paid account. The person needs to have an Apple ID that’s enough!  If my answer helps you then accept it.